# Equivalent of python2 chr(int) in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
# python2
print(chr(174))
?

# python3
print(chr(174))
®
```

I'm looking for the equivalent of chr() from python2. I believe this is due to python 3 returning unicode characters rather than ASCII.

Comment: You should say whether you want `bytes` or an `str` string. It's not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this would be the closest equivalent:

```
>>> print(chr(174).encode('ascii', errors='replace'))
b'?'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this for now! Seems to work.
`print(chr(174).encode('ascii', errors='replace').decode("utf-8"))`

Comment: Yes, although note, what it returns won't be convertable back to the correct code-point, i.e. `ord(chr(174).encode('ascii', errors='replace').decode("utf-8"))` won't be `174`

Answer (score 6):

Actually, in Py3 `chr` is equivalent of `unichr` in Py2. You can use `bytes` or `bytearray`.

For example:

```
>>> print(bytes([174]))
b'\xae'
```

or

```
>>> print(bytearray([174]))
bytearray(b'\xae')
```

**b'\xae'** equals to **?**